# How to specify x and y axis for plotting dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I would like to spcify x and y axis to draw data in dataframe in Python.

For example, I have four columns in dataframe. And here's my code.

```
df.plot(x=df['a'], y=df['b'], label=df['c'])
```

---

It throws an error saying: These values come from 'b' column.

> "KeyError: '[  500.8   567.2   487.2   444.4  1371.6   714.4  1157.4
>   476.8   345.4\n  1076.4   881.8   813.    452.6   663.6   606.8   469.2   805.2   487.4\n   497.8   440.    127.     68.6  1494.2   716.4  1447.     97.8   110.\n  1126.4  1422.8    92.4  1000.8] not in index'"

Thank you for the help in advance.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**df.plot** takes the column labels as x and y, not the data itself

`df.plot(x='a', y='b')`
might work

Use https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html as reference to the arguments needed in pandas

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html as examples

Answer (score 6):

The correct use is to pass column names:

```
df.plot(x='a', y='b', label='c')
```

The error is pandas trying to use the entire column `df['b']` as a column name.

Answer (score 4):

Its a simple mistake. Instead of `df['a']` ...  just past the column name i.e

```
df.plot(x='a', y='b', label='c')
```